# Trying to parse an RSS feed but missing 1 part

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to parse an rss feed. I can parse the BBC's feed ok. But when I try and parse the independant's feed I cannot catch the link to an image I need.
(Source of feed is: http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/rss)
Here is an extract from the feed. Its 1 item.

```
<item>
<title>Juventus join race to sign Carlos Tevez claim Corinthians</title>
<guid>http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/transfers/juventus-join-race-to-sign- 
carlos-tevez-claim-corinthians-2314261.html</guid>  
<link>http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/transfers/juventus-join-race-to-sign- 
carlos-tevez-claim-corinthians-2314261.html</link>
<description>
<img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/multimedia/dynamic/00623/tevez_623081k.jpg"  
style="padding-right:5px;margin-right:5px" align="left" >
<p>
Corinthians president Andres Sanchez claims Juventus have entered the race to 
sign Carlos Tevez but insists his own club will not increase their offer for 
the want-away Argentinian.
</p> </description>
<category>Transfers</category>
<pubDate>Fri, 15 Jul 2011 10:46:12   +0100</pubDate>
</item>
```

The problem is extracting 'img src=' since I want the url to the thumbnail image to display.

I'm parsing the rss feed with NSXMLParser and doing the parsing in there following delegates.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

if(nil != qualifiedName)
{
    elementName = qualifiedName;
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
{
    self.currentItem = [[[BlogRss alloc]init]autorelease];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) 
{
    self.currentItem.mediaUrl = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
}   
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) 
{
    self.currentItemValue = [NSMutableString string];

} 
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"] )
{
    self.currentItemValue = [NSMutableString string];
} 
else 
{
    self.currentItemValue = nil;
}   
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
 {
if(nil != qName)
{
    elementName = qName;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    self.currentItem.title = self.currentItemValue;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
{
    self.currentItem.description = self.currentItemValue;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
{
    self.currentItem.linkUrl = self.currentItemValue;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"])
{
    self.currentItem.guidUrl = self.currentItemValue;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
     self.currentItem.pubDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:self.currentItemValue formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
    [formatter release];
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{
    [[self rssItems] addObject:self.currentItem];
}
}
```

I've NSLog'd out

```
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
{
    self.currentItem.description = self.currentItemValue;
}
```

The contents of self.currentItemValue and it does not contain any of the img url text.

What is it that I am missing. Is it not valid XML so using NSXMLParser will never work for me?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an XML wrapper around NSXMLParser.

The one I have used is [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) but there are several others out there.

Given an xPath (//item in your case); the wrappers will provide you with `NSDictionary`, so you can retrieve the values using the `valueForKey:` method of `NSDictionary`.

It is a lot easier and reusable than creating a custom parser for your specific class.

Comment: Ok can i just plug TouchXML into the project in place of everywhere I used NSXMLParser and then have access to the added functionality you mentioned without losing the work I've done to get this far? Thanks for your advice Zebs

Comment: @Code: [This](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/) is the tutorial I used to learn how to use Touch XML, it's pretty simple and straightforward, there should be newer ones if you google TouchXML tutorial, you should be able to replace it quite easily, specially if you followed MVC conventions.